# Programmatically move a view Android

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an imageView that I want to move given a specific situation.

Initially I have a Relative layout with two textViews and an imageview. The textViews are oriented with one above the other. The imageView is set

```
android:layout_below="@id/text_view1"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_view2".
```

In the logic text_view2 is removed when a specific condition is met. I want to programmatically move the imageView to the end of text_view1 when this condition is met. Essentially when text_view2 is removed, I want to set the imageView to

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_view1"
```

I don't believe setting X,Y,Z values is appropriate here because programmatically, I don't know where the  imageView will show up given different screen sizes, and densities. I just need it to move to the end of the first textView.

Comment: i don´t understand all the context and design but i think with ConstraintLayout is easy to do this, could you show the design with initial situation and expected situation?

Comment: I'd suggest not using RelativeLayout: either put the two TextViews in a (vertical) LinearLayout and this together with the ImageView in another (horizontal) LinearLayout. Or use ConstraintLayout: it's not as easy to understand but you can achieve everything in just one ViewGroup. In your case, a [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier)  will do the trick

Comment: @BömachtBlau
First two linearLayouts would be a nightmare to attempt placing the imageView in the proper place virtually impossible.
Also, the barrier is designed to prevent a view from moving beyond a specific plane on the screen. Unless you can help me with HOW to do this with a Barrier, I don't think it is much help.

Comment: I have considered using a ConstraintLayout. I am trying to figure out how to move the image to the end of the line above. if there is a constraint to a specific view and that view is designated as "gone", the constrained view will jump to the top left of the screen... ie it will not have a constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams). You will need to manipulate the layout rules in the layout params as follows:

```
// Make textView2 invisible
tv2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
// Get the LayoutParams of the ImageView
val ivParams = iv.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
// Change the rule to be to the right of textView1
ivParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.id)
// Since the placement of textView2 is changing, request a layout.
iv.requestLayout()
```

Consider using "END_OF" instead of "RIGHT_OF".

Comment: I had to add an additional addRule to get the image in the exact proper place, but this works beautifully, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You can either place the `View`s in a nested `LinearLayout` or use a `ConstraintLayout` with a `Barrier`.

It is generally recommended to use `ConstraintLayout` because nested `LinearLayout`s are bad for performance but since `ConstraintLayout` takes some getting used to, I did not want to omit the other option.

To demonstrate the two approaches I've set up a small example with a `LinearLayout` and a `ConstraintLayout` in the same screen:

[image: a LinearLayout and a ConstraintLayout in the same screen]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragment.TabTwoFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:background="#cccccc">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#44ff0000"
                android:maxWidth="160dp"
                android:text="Upper TextView\nin\n nested\n LinearLayout" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longTextViewInLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#4400ff00"
                android:maxWidth="160dp"
                android:text="Lower TextView in nested LinearLayout" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImageView"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:background="#666666">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shortTextViewInConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#44ff0000"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:text="Upper TextView\nin\n nested\nConstraintLayout"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/longTextViewInConstraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/longTextViewInConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4400ff00"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:text="Lower TextView in ConstraintLayout"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shortTextViewInConstraintLayout" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="end"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="shortTextViewInConstraintLayout, longTextViewInConstraintLayout" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutImageView"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

If the `ImageView` is clicked, the longer `TextView` will disappear and the `ImageView` will move closer to the short `TextView`. The animations are provided by [Android's transition framework](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions), so basically all you have to do is trigger the transition by calling `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()`

For demonstration purposes, I've placed all the code in one method. Please note that normally one would have the `TransitionSet` as field of the `Fragment` so that it does not have to be recreated every time you need it. (The code is in Java since Android Studio supports automatic translation to Kotlin if required but not the other way round ;-) )

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    TransitionSet ts = new TransitionSet();
    ts.addTransition( new ChangeBounds());
    ts.addTransition(new Slide());

    View imageViewInLinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutImageView);
    imageViewInLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup)getView(), ts);
            view.findViewById(R.id.longTextViewInLinearLayout).setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    });

    View imageViewInConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutImageView);
    imageViewInConstraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup)getView(), ts);
            view.findViewById(R.id.longTextViewInConstraintLayout).setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    });
}
```